# Colored string is printing in reverse order not forward

Tags: string, assembly, x86, bios

In assembly language I want to print a colored string
`"--  WELCOME TO E-VOTING MANAGEMENT SYSTEM  --"` in forward order but the string is printing in reverse order. Here is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNDKr.png).
Below is my code:

```
;print screen
mov cx,45
mov si,-1
c1:
inc si
mov al,msg3[si]
mov ah,9
mov bh,0
mov bl,00110100b
int 10h
loop c1
```

Comment: Nice effect :) The int10/9 function does not move the cursor. However it does take a repeat count in `CX`. You print the first character 45 times, then the second 44 times and so on. This means the last repetition remains visible, hence the apparent reversal.

Answer (score 1):

This BIOS.WriteCharacterWithAttribute function 09h does not advance the cursor. You can use the BIOS.Teletype function 0Eh for that purpose.

Since the BIOS.WriteCharacterWithAttribute function 09h uses the `CX` register for a repetition count, it will be best to not use `CX` for a loop counter. Below code use `DI`. This code also avoids using the `LOOP` instruction which is infamous for being slow! See [Why is LOOP so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565046/why-is-loop-so-slow/21565600#21565600).

```
;print screen
  mov  di, 45
  mov  si, -1
  mov  cx, 1       ; Repetition count
  mov  bx, 0034h   ; DisplayPage 0, Color RedOnCyan
TheLoop:
  inc  si
  mov  al, msg3[si]
  mov  ah, 09h
  int  10h
  mov  ah, 0Eh
  int  10h
  dec  di
  jnz  TheLoop
```

It is possible to use the offset `SI` by which we address the characters as our loop counter. In a string that has 45 characters, the very last character will be at offset 44, so that's the value we need to have reached at loop exit:

```
;print screen
  mov  si, -1
  mov  cx, 1       ; Repetition count
  mov  bx, 0034h   ; DisplayPage 0, Color RedOnCyan
TheLoop:
  inc  si
  mov  al, msg3[si]
  mov  ah, 09h
  int  10h
  mov  ah, 0Eh
  int  10h
  cmp  si, 44
  jne  TheLoop
```

One further improvement would start the offset `SI` at 0, using the one byte shorter encoding of `xor si, si`. This influences the way we need to check for the loop exit!

```
;print screen
  xor  si, si
  mov  cx, 1       ; Repetition count
  mov  bx, 0034h   ; DisplayPage 0, Color RedOnCyan
TheLoop:
  mov  al, msg3[si]
  mov  ah, 09h
  int  10h
  mov  ah, 0Eh
  int  10h
  inc  si
  cmp  si, 45
  jb   TheLoop
```

And instead of using a fixed count for the string length, you could also easily use a string terminator like zero.

```
;print screen
  xor  si, si
  mov  cx, 1       ; Repetition count
  mov  bx, 0034h   ; DisplayPage 0, Color RedOnCyan
TheLoop:
  mov  al, msg3[si]
  test al, al
  jz   Done
  mov  ah, 09h
  int  10h
  mov  ah, 0Eh
  int  10h
  inc  si
  jmp  TheLoop
Done:

  ...

msg3 db "--  WELCOME TO E-VOTING MANAGEMENT SYSTEM  --", 0
```

Comment: You already have SI as a loop counter, you could just `cmp si, 45` or `cmp si,di` instead of also counting down another register.